# Why does my Vue component require :key?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small Vue.js component which displays a favorite star icon. Clicking on the icon favorites/unfavorites the element. So far I have only implemented the UI part, which looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div :key="favorite">
    <a v-on:click="toggleFavorite" style="cursor: pointer">
      <i v-show="favorite" class="text-warning fas fa-star"></i>
      <i v-show="!favorite" class="text-warning far fa-star"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      favorite: true,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite() {
      this.favorite = !this.favorite
    }
  },
  props: ['team-id'],
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

As you can see, the logic is pretty simple.

This works well, but one thing that bothers me is that, if I remove the `:key` property from my template, the icon is not updated when I click on it (even though I have checked that the underlying property *is* indeed updated correctly). Adding `:key` makes it work, I imagine because it forces Vue.js to completely re-render the component when `favorite` is updated.

Why is this happening? I'm fairly new to the world of JS frameworks, so forgive any obvious stuff I might be missing. I did some research online but couldn't find an explanation. I just want to make sure I'm doing things the right way and not merely hacking around the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems to be a general issue of FontAwesome CSS regardless the framework.
There is an issue on github and here the same issue with react https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11967

To prove that, here is a simplified version of the same example but using bootstrap icons

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { 
      fav: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"
></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <a v-on:click="fav = !fav" style="cursor: pointer">
      <i v-show="fav" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
      <i v-show="!fav" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a problem of the font in fact. This is a problem of reactivity as the font is not preserved and the patch wouldn't work. They (font vendor) might try to solve the issue by using some kind of caching mechanism. Bootstrap icon once placed in the DOM the icon is shown from the cache there after. Make sure to use `replace` method whatever framework you use.

Answer (score 3):

Vue **patches** with the virtual DOM whenever it is necessary. That is, whenever vue detects the changes on the DOM, it patches them for faster performance. And patching in the DOM will not change the icon or image. You need to replace the DOM instead.

Thus, vue provides the way for us whenever we need to change the DOM by replacing method, we can use `:key` binding.

So, `:key` binding can be used to force replacement of an element/component instead of reusing it.

The following whole html div will be replaced whenever there is change in `favorite` data as we're `:key` binding on it:

```
<div :key="favorite">
    <a v-on:click="toggleFavorite" style="cursor: pointer">
      <i v-show="favorite" class="text-warning fas fa-star"></i>
      <i v-show="!favorite" class="text-warning far fa-star"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

---

This is why vue forcefully allows us to use `:key` binding inside a loop as there's need of replacing the elements inside the loop whenever it detects the changes in the `data`. This is made compulsory from `2.2.0+` and ESLint also have implemented this feature so that if you miss `:key` binding inside the loop, then you'll see the error on that line when you use editor that supports eslint, so that you can fix the error.

Just an opinion, the strict requirement of the `:key` binding should be removed from the vue as we might want a loop of `predefined data` and don't want to change the DOM but we still use the `v-for` loop for listing bigger data. But it might be rare case though.

---

Read carefully on the [documentation for :key binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) and then you'll have an idea.

The `:key` binding can be useful when you want to:

> Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component
>
> Trigger transitions

---

1. Use `:key` binding to replace the DOM. Remember it slower the performance as it replace the whole DOM that is bound to the element.
2. Don't use `:key` binding when you don't want to replace the DOM or
   you think there's no `data` changes detection required. This will
   allow vue to perform better without `:key` binding.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the problem here is that you're changing your root data object. To preserve reactivity, you shouldn't change the root data object after you've instantiated Vue.

[Here is your code](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/kyeky6o5/7/) in a simple Vue. I didn't need :key to make it work. I would keep :key for inside loops.

**markup**

```
<div id="vueRoot">
  <a v-on:click="toggleFavorite" style="cursor: pointer">
    <i v-show="store.favorite" class="text-warning fas fa-star">Fav</i>
    <i v-show="!store.favorite" class="text-warning far fa-star">Not fav</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**code**

```
vm = new Vue({
  el : "#vueRoot",
  data() {
    return { store :{
      favorite: true
    }}
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite() {
      this.store.favorite = !this.store.favorite
    }
  }
}
);
```

This is a working example with minimal changes. From what you've showed us, you should just have <i> element, then do what you want with a dynamic class list, like...

```
<i :class="['text-warning','fa-star',store.favorite?'fas':'far']"></i>
```

Comment: @Bert ok but it's unrelated to this problem, no ?

Comment: Can you define "changing your root data object"? If I understand correctly, everything that could change at some point in the component's lifecycle should be nested one more level like you did, is that correct? And why is that important? Do you have any pointers to Vue.js docs/posts/etc.? I read some stuff in the Vue docs but it only says you can't add/remove root properties, not that you can't change their value. Thanks! :)

Comment: Re having a dynamic class: the reason I don't do that is that FontAwesome now renders icons with JS, so if I change the class dynamically the icon is not going to be updated unfortunately, I need to use two different DOM elements.

Comment: It's explained [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). "Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance." The reason is that Vue injects getters and setters into the `data` objects at initialization. This is how reactivity is implemented. If you add properties low down using the specified methods (splice, Vue.set) Vue can initialize these new properties on the fly. If you rip out the reactive object and replace it. Vue has no way of knowing, and you're left with just a dumb js object sittin there.

Comment: Ok I think I'm spoutin before thinkin. You're never changing the root data object. You changed the favorite property on that object. I don't know why your favourite wasn't updating. Maybe you should try putting keys on the i elements, to make sure they are recreated. It could be due to the FontAwesome behaviour that you talk about.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the :key, it's only necessary in v-for loops. I would suggest you remove it and replace your v-show with a v-if and v-else directive.

```
  <i v-if="favorite" class="text-warning fas fa-star"></i>
  <i v-else class="text-warning far fa-star"></i>
```

v-if removes and addes the section to the DOM whereas v-show just hides it so this way well resolve your issue

Comment: Yes, useful. But not _required_ except in the case of loops.