# Getting sum of elements in a table using vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using vuejs and laravel and I want to get total amount in a table which contains quantity, unit price and their totals. Now I want to get their total after looping the database elements and using v-if to get certain elements. How do I do this...thanks in advance. 
[this is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gW4G.png)

This is my code

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <th>Decription</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Create on</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item, key in pass" v-if="list.quotation_no === item.quotation_id">
              <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.quantity }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.unit_price }}</td>                  
              <td>{{ item.quantity * item.unit_price }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.created_at }}</td><br>
            </tr>     
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: You can use watcher or computed properties for this

Comment: Sum of price is a nonsense value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method:

```
rowTotal(base) {
   return this.pass.reduce( (sum,cur) => sum+cur[base] , 0);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
     <th>Total</th>
     <th>{{ rowTotal('quantity') }}</th>
     <th>{{ rowTotal('unit_price') }}</th>
     <th>{{ sumTotal }}</th>
   </tr>     
</tfoot>
```

But this will total of your `pass` as this is not checking the condition `list.quotation_no === item.quotation_id`. For this, you need to use a computed method which filters the data:

```
filteredPass() {
 return this.pass.filter( x => list.quotation === x.quotation_id);
}
```

You'll also need to define a **computed value** for multiplying sum of the total as we can't calculate inline in data-binding:

```
computed: {
  sumTotal() {
    const summation = this.filteredPass();
    return summation.reduce((sum, cur) => sum += cur.unit_price * cur.quantity, 0)
  }
}
```

Now, you can modify the `v-for` in your html. Just replace the following:

```
<tr v-for="item, key in pass" v-if="list.quotation_no === item.quotation_id">
```

With this:

```
<tr v-for="(item, key) in filteredPass" :key="key">
<!-- better to use :key -->
```

Here are some list of links that you might be interested to watch:

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[computed properties and watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

[Why key binding is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931387/why-does-my-vue-component-require-key/48933619#48933619)

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the late reaction. I did as instracted but got this error:: app.js:54163 TypeError: this.pass.reduce is not a function

Comment: is this.pass an array defined in data?

Comment: It is defined as a prop