# Render unicode list in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

Im converting an old project to Vue.js, and Im having trouble rendering a select list that contains Font Awesome icons inside it.

My code was...

```
<select id='fa_select'>
  <option value='fa fa-address-book'>&#xf2b9; fa-address-book</option>
  <option value='fa fa-address-book-o'>&#xf2ba; fa-address-book-o</option>
  etc etc etc 
</select>
```

Which works fine in the old project using bootstrap and Jquery.

But when I put this list into Vue.js however, it doesnt work.  I have vue-bootstrap installed, and have fa-icons working.  For instance, I can do

```
<i class='fa fa-phone'></i>
```

And it displays just fine, so I know the stylesheet for Font Awesome icons is importing and working properly.

So then, why won't they display in the list??

I also tried v-html as well, just incase I needed to wrap it as html, that also didnt work either.

```
<option value='fa fa-address-book' v-html="'&#xf2b9; fa-address-book'"></option>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Vue component require :key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931387/why-does-my-vue-component-require-key)

Comment: I dont see how that question answers this one?  Im not looping and just want to display unicode characters.

Comment: There's an answer to know that's a bug in font-awesome.

Comment: Are you using FontAwesome’s JavaScript or its CSS?

Comment: Installed it with npm install, then Im importing it @import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';   Works fine otherwise.  I can use the icons everywhere.  Unless I use unicode, like as shown above.  So I think this is more of a unicode/vue js thing

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad.  I was missing a piece of styling code that I forgot to bring over.

```
#fa_select {
   font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'sans-serif';
}
```