# When should I use key vs. v-model for an input?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to vue.js and stumbled across this section in the [Conditional Rendering documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key), describing how vue tries to reuse as many components as possible. In the example an input is used, if you only would like to override different properties of the object, its straight forward. If you would like to exchange the whole element, you can use the key property.

Using `key="whatever"` on an input element works just fine, but when I use `v-model="myAnswer"` it has the same effect in the examples from the documentation.

```js
let data = {happy: true, why: '', whyN: ''}

let standart = new Vue({
  el: '#standart',
  data: data
});

let withKey = new Vue({
  el: '#withKey',
  data: data
});

let withModel = new Vue({
  el: '#withModel',
  data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="standart">
  <i>Without anything</i>
  <template v-if="happy">
    <label>Why are you happy?</label>
    <input placeholder="Because it's cool">
  </template>
  <template v-else>
  <label>Why are you unhappy?</label>
  <input placeholder="It's to slow">
  </template>
  <button @click="happy = !happy">Toggle</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="withKey">
  <i>With key</i>
  <template v-if="happy">
    <label>Why are you happy?</label>
    <input placeholder="Because it's cool" key="happy">
  </template>
  <template v-else>
  <label>Why are you unhappy?</label>
  <input placeholder="It's to slow" key="unhappy">
  </template>
  <button @click="happy = !happy">Toggle</button>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="withModel">
  <i>With model</i>
  <template v-if="happy">
    <label>Why are you happy?</label>
    <input placeholder="Because it's cool" v-model="why">
  </template>
  <template v-else>
  <label>Why are you unhappy?</label>
  <input placeholder="It's to slow" v-model="whyN">
  </template>
  <button @click="happy = !happy">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

I would like to know, how these functions compare, when to use which and overall what the advantages of each of them are. To me, the documentation doeesn't make the best job explaining.

Comment: This will help you understanding about using key : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48933619/2138752

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually you need a key in lists and the keys need to come from a source so that a key of a given entry does not change over the time. 
If you use a UUID generator, the keys will change at every re-render and you don't want this. Therefore the best solution is to use something like json-server for mocking things up or using a real backend api.

There are situations like with OAuth2 where by default you cannot send a POST object with Content-type application/json and the data in the body object since the protocol expects something www-form-urlencoded.

In this case you need something like

```
<form ref="someForm">
  <input name="nameofinput" ref="myFancyInput" />
</form>
```

this way by accessing this.$refs you can do something like:

```
this.$refs["myFancyInput"]="somevalue"
this.$refs["someForm"].submit();
```

The contents of the input's value can be also a JSON, since JSON is just a string formatted in a given way.

Then in the backend you can process that as you want.

http://www.davidepugliese.com/csv-download-ajax-and-spring/

As for the v-model annotation, that is just shortcut for something like:

```
<input :value="someVar" @input="functionName($event)" />


functionName(event) {
   console.log(event)

}
```